# Excel Data Distribution

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, statistics

I have a machine that produce goods by work order generated from database. The quantity of goods per work order varies from 1 to 5,000. I am trying to analyze the efficiency of the machine as I think that bigger work orders do not translate into better productivity, at least not for all type of material we are using. I have generated qty per work order and the average production speed (parts/hr) from the database. But I do not know how to put them into a distribution chart. I want to put qty per work order on x-axis and speed on y-axis so I can see what qty gives the fastest production rate. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: They're just numbers, you can chart anything you want.  Put the X and Y values in two columns, select them, and insert a chart.  Speed may not be the best parameter to chart, though.  A more directly related value is production time.  If there is no change in productivity with quantity, the time will be a straight line.  If you do get an effect from quantity, the line will curve.

Comment: The production time (in hours per part) would just be 1/(production rate).  But I think the production rate (in parts/hr) is just fine as a statistic that you're trying to maximize.  To make the graph, just select all of the x- and y-data (Excel will assume the leftmost column is x) and then choose one of the chart types.  I'd suggest Marked Scatter to start.  Let us know how it works out.

Comment: Just to clarify, I was referring to total production time rather than time per piece.  But try plotting various statistics to see the curves, which will tell you which one is the most useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

My Dear,

1. Assume : In Column A you have entered " Quantity per Work Order "
   and In column B "Average Production Speed "
2. Select the data of Column A and B
3. Go to Insert and Select Scatter Plot
4. You will see a Scatter Diagram of the plotted points
5. The Rule is : If there is wide scatter on the graph then there is no correlation but if points are close and forming upward or downward trend then there is a relation.
6. If Trend is upward; implies Positive Correlation : So if X increases then Y  Increases and If X decreases Y also decreases.
7. If Trend is downward; implies Negative Correlation : So if X Increases then Y decreases and if X decreases then Y Increases.
8. To get the Quantitative Values of the relationship, you can find Karl Pearson's Correlation Coefficient (r) by inserting the formula :

Select a Cell
Enter the formula :  =CORREL(A2:A100, B2:B100 )
YOu will get a value of r
If you get r=1 or -1 then there is a perfect Positive or Negative Correlation

In your case I presume the value of r may be around -0.85 say, based on your explanation, which says that r square ie. (-.85)^2 = 0.7256 indicating that in 73 % of cases the production speed reduces when order size increases.

By the theory of Regression Lines you can also fit an equation to the given data and also can test the significance of the test.